# How to hibernate per login

Tags: windows, hibernate, multiple-users

In Windows XP/7 without using a virtual machine, how to hibernate per login?

That is to logout with open applications and work in progress. Then at the next login with that user id, to carry on exactly where you left off. Even if in the meantime other users have logged in and used the system. This way to have different projects available where you left off, sometimes only coming back to them after a long interval.

[Fast User Switching](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279765) is unsuitable because 1) If another user shuts the computer down all running programs will be closed, even those open for other logins and any unsaved work will be lost. 2) Overall system performance for other users, might be affected by programs left running.

Comment: You can't technically suspend users like they way you described using Windows.  You would need a separate OS running underneath Windows that saves and resumes copies of itself (ie a hypervisor).  There are OSes that can do this, but they are probably beyond your price range.

Comment: This would be the accepted answer if it wasn't a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't technically suspend users like they way you described using Windows. You would need a separate OS running underneath Windows that saves and resumes copies of itself (ie a hypervisor). There are OSes that can do this, but they are probably beyond your price range. – [surfasb](https://superuser.com/users/24500/surfasb) Feb 13 '11 at 2:41

Answer (score 2):

In windows 7 you can use switch users instead of logout, this will keep all your programs running and login as other users.

Hope this helps.